# Which scenes in The Burrow are exclusive to the Half-Blood Prince film?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison

The *Half-Blood Prince* film mostly takes place in Hogwarts, but it has many scenes in and around The Burrow that I don't recall happening in the book. Which of these are exclusive to the film?

I'm happy to take quite broad answers. For example, if a conversation or battle happened in both the book and the film, but only the film had it in The Burrow, then I'm happy to hear about that as well as any blatant "this simply didn't happen in the book" moments.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a ScreenRant article](https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-worst-changes-book-better-than-movies/) there's a scene at the Burrows that is added in solely because there was a stagnation in action. It involves the Death Eaters led by Bellatrix attacking the Burrows and chasing Harry and friends through the marshlands only to run away mid chase. The article says it was a useless addition because there were no lasting consequences, no one gets hurt, and the Death Eaters just run away.

I'm not sure how helpful this is but I definitely remember this scene in the movie but I can't recall ever reading about it happening in the books.

Comment: “no lasting consequences”—yeah, the Burrow is burnt down but fine the next time it’s needed. Because it never happens in the books, so having consequences in the movie(s) would mean requiring even more divergence (like with the other differences).